# MVC application crashes due to System.Web.Mvc not containing the html namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace ‘System.Web.Mvc’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071392/the-type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc)

When I compile my MVC4 project locally I receive the following error:

```
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Html' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Line 25:         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
Line 26:         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
Line 27:         <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />    <--- this line
Line 28:         <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
Line 29:         <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
```

What could be causing this? If I push the code to AppHarbor it builds and runs correctly

Comment: I can't tell you how badly the VS 11 beta borked my regular VS/SQL installations.

Comment: +1 and lol @Tyr for "borked"... it must be election season! =p

Answer (score 19):

You also need to set the **DLL** reference as copy local.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding System.Web.Mvc namespace to the list of assemblies in the compilation section

```
<compilation debug="true">
    <assemblies>
       <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why is it coming , however you can try adding reference to this dll **System.Web.Mvc.dll** explicitly to your project. The System.Web.Mvc.Html resides in this assembly only.

Comment: I'm not sure either. I ended up recreating a web api project and now it works. It might have been caused by web api not being officially supported by MonoDevelop/Mono yet.