# Referenced namespace not being recognized

Tags: c#, asp.net

I cant get the namespace system.runtime.caching to be recognized despite adding the reference. Based on research to similar problems, I've checked the target framework and all seems in order (currently 4.5.2).

Has anyone got a suggestion on how to solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried capitalizing the name of the namespace in your using directive properly? It appears that you've written `caching`, while it has to be `Caching`.

Comment: Yes, this not a case typo - edited the picture to be more accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the problem is you are putting your code in `App_Code` folder. Files in this folder are treated as content by default. You can solve this issue setting **Build Action** to **Compile** for *.cs* files in this folder.

However, you shouldn't use this folder for code, it will surely cause problems. I recommend you to move your code to another folder `Infrastructure` or `Code`.

Comment: Well what do you know! That worked - well done and thank you. I need  to do some reading up on the purpose of the App_Code folder, I always thought it was there specifically for your .cs files.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to add a reference to System.Core in your project. See these links, particularly the first one:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/804fdc52-1082-4f93-b256-902ab300d78d/problem-with-namespacesystemruntimecaching?forum=vbgeneral

[The type or namespace name 'Caching' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200018/the-type-or-namespace-name-caching-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-run)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting Visual Studio? I added the reference and I was able to use it as a namespace.