# IIS Website Alias - The type or namespace name does not exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, servicestack, alias

I have an mvc website hosted in iis 8.5.

What I want is to add an alias, (Add application), under the mvc website, to point to my service stack api project.  So I can call the api from within the website e.g:

```
http://localhost/api
```

However I am getting this message:

CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

The mvc website runs fine so there is a reference to system.web.

Comment: possible duplicate of [The type or namespace name does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071392/the-type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc)

Comment: I create a new mvc website and bind it in iis.  I create a new web application with a single default.aspx file.  I add the web application as an alias to the mvc website and receive the exact same error.

Comment: It seems I can get it to work but only if I add all the references needed by mvc to the website running under the alias, surely this can not be correct?

Answer (score 1):

Check the version of .net that the app pool runs. In IIS manager check the app pool, make sure it is V4.0

Comment: like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071392/the-type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc

Comment: Yes the application pool is v4.0.  Should it run under the same application pool as the main mvc website or its own app pool?

Comment: It should not matter, what version of .net does your service stack api run. Check the configuration for the project, what version is the actual project set to?

Comment: SS proj set to v4.0. MVC webiste v4.5

Comment: I have just created a test website with one default.aspx file and added it as an application to the mvc website and I get the same error, so I'm confident its not an issue with the SS project.