# System.web.Mvc does not exist in the namespace system.web - but it is there ~

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, reference

It's been more than 2 days, i'm stuck in a situation. I have several projects in a solution. Everything was working fine previously, but when i interacted with `TFS`, and merged content of solution, I started having build error saying:

`Error  566 The type or namespace name 'Mvc' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

**but** it is there! I tried to look up for solutions, and been through [THIS](http://catharsis.codeplex.com/workitem/7936), [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071392/the-type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc) and several other posts, but nothing worked (eg: i tried cleaning, rebuilding, setting copy local flag true, etc.). and could not understand few solutions.

The **solution that worked for me** was to manually updating the reference file. What i did was, i deleted the `system.web.mvc` from references and added again as reference (from other project) and it worked.
**but** everytime, I cannot go to references of each project, delete reference and add new one (because I have several projects, and this is time consuming and not a proper solution). Kindly guide me, I'm seriously stuck. any suggestions/help?

(Other ifno: I'm using `MVC4` with `VS2012`, `windows7`. No one else having same issue after interacting with TFS stuff. which means problem started in my pc. may be due to any update or version changing after updates? anything alike, any one knows?)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem before but with other library. Check .NET Target Framework of your own project and your Nuget Package reference (MVC packages) if they have both same .NET Target Framework.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems caused by the recent MVC security update. There are some known issues. You can find more details on [Microsoft Asp.Net MVC Security Update MS14-059 broke my build!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx)