# cannot resolve View "index" in mvc5 visual studio project

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am running Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 2 (after repairing was previously update 3). I created a `Homecontroller` in a MVC application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace HelloMVC.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I have a file called `Index` in the `Views/Home` folder, but the `View()` is colored red and when I hover over it it says cannot resolve view `Index`.

if i delete the index page again and try `create razor views > create view Index` i get the error `cannot perform this action, most likely due to errors in the source code`

My guess is that it has something to do with Razor views not working correctly but I have tried a repair and this does not seem to fix it.

I can't seem to find any differences with my other pc where this code works just fine.

When I build the solution and run it everything seems to work  so i'm guessing the problem is something editor related

Comment: Have you built the application?

Comment: Yes but it does not change anything, the same project works on my other pc when i run the application i get a compiler error. i'll add this to the original post

Comment: I don't see the Ajax namespace in the code you posted

Comment: Thats from the web.config file there all the namespaces are added

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071392/the-type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc

Comment: This did fix one of the two problems i was having. When i run the solution it works but in the editor the View() in the home controller is still saying cannot resolve view 'index' but it works when i run the project