# ASP.NET MVC 5 Error

Tags: ajax, reference, namespaces, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm starting to learn ASP.NET MVC and 5 when I try debug my solution, this error appears:

```
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Ajax' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Mvc;
```

I try to get the reference Mvc.Ajax, but my MVC package is installed the last update.

Error to build the solution:

```
Line 22: using System.Web.WebPages;
Line 23: using System.Web.Mvc;
Line 24: using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
Line 25: using System.Web.Mvc.Html;
Line 26: using System.Web.Routing;
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the same problem or not, but notice what this question added to their question, and add the same:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071392/the-type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc

Comment: Clean your solution and rebuild

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Manage NuGet Packages
2. Try to find out "Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax" Online
3. Install it.
4. Installing "Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Ajax", adds "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" file. 
   Then U can Search how to use Ajax.BeginForm
   Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just open the console manager

**Tools**>**Nuget Pakage Manager**>**Pakage Manager Console** 
and paste

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.2.3
```