# Dbcontext could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

Wait! Before you mark this as a duplicate question:

I did use NuGet and installed EntityFramework 6.1.3 Stable Release for my project.
I am referencing System.Data.Entities in the code file.
I did try to install older versions of EF through NuGet.
But the error is still there. It's an API project and under References->.NET Framework I see EntityFramework (6.1.3) there.
I also tried to build/re-build solution, refresh project, and restart Visual Studio.

How to properly reference EntityFramework for an API project in Visual Studio Web Express 2015?

**Update**: Not much to say except that I've searched far and wide and found same issues fixed with what I've already done. But these solutions didn't help.

Comment: What framework are you targeting? If you're not targeting 4.5, I would try that.

Comment: @JonathanCarroll The API project doesn't have the option to select version of target platform. But It seems to be 4.5.2 for any other non-API type of project, if I create one for test purposes.

Comment: Just to verify, you're referencing System.Data.Entity, correct?

Comment: @JonathanCarroll Yes, sir.

Comment: Is this a compile time error or runtime error?

Comment: Can you be very specific about the type of project you are using.  If you happen to be creating a Portable Class Library project, versions of EF prior to 7 are not supported.

Comment: @Becuzz Compile. IDE highlights DbContext and anything related to it with red, squiggly lines.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Visual C#->Web->Class Library(Package). I'm watching a video tutorial of a tutor who's using a 2013 version instead of 2015, but they created the same thing and it works for them after they used NuGet to install EF.

Comment: In that case, open up the references for your project and look for the EF references.  I bet they have a little yellow triangle by them, which usually means you are targeting an older version of .Net than the library needs.  In any case, that triangle means the DLL isn't compatible with the project you have (usually due to settings of some sort) and you need to work out what is different between what you have and what it needs.

Comment: @Becuzz Do you mean these references?: http://i.imgur.com/HUxHgS1.png 

I don't see any triangles.

Comment: That looks like it (slightly different than what I am used to since I use VS2013).  Just as a "make sure we didn't forget something stupid" check, the code files in question all have the right using statements right?

Comment: @Becuzz As far as I'm aware, my using statements are correct: http://i.imgur.com/BxmuWy3.png

Comment: The fact that it doesn't like System.Web is suspicious to me.  Take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071392/the-type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc).  Try cleaning and making sure all the dlls are set to copy local.  Also make sure there isn't some project that yours is depending on that isn't building for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created wrong project.
Should've created Class Library from Visual C# section.
Instead, created Class Library (Package) from Visual C#->Web section.