# The type or namespace name 'Dependencies' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Http'

Tags: c#, asp.net, teamcity, system.web.http

I updated my project from .NET4 -> .NET461 and it builds without any errors on my local machine. However, when I push it and start team city build, then it crashes with the error from this question's topic. Team city machine is also equipped with .NET461. I can't install the `Dependencies` namespace from nuget in any way because it should be built into `System.Web.Http` module. How to fix it?

Comment: You can view [that problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11071392/the-type-or-namespace-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-system-web-mvc) Possibly dublicate of that.

Comment: I did what the answer suggested and it didn't help.

Comment: What build runner are you using - MSBuild or Visual Studio? What versions are they set to - can you provide a screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the TargetFramework parameter in the packages.config

In Package Manager Console simply run:

```
Update-Package -Reinstall
```