# MVC3 on Visual Studio 2010 Build Errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3

Every once in a while, almost daily, I get build errors when building MVC 3 project in Visual Studio 2010, the errors are all related to unknown MVC 3 classes.

`Unknown type System.Web.Mvc.Controller`

What I do then is:

- Close Visual Studio
- Uninstall MVC 3
- Install MVC 3
- Open Visual Studio
- Build the project

Everything is fine, no build errors, build succeeded.

How can I get rid of this annoying problem?

Comment: It's not entirely the same, but this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13149587/6741868. Basically it involves setting 'Copy-Local' to true for that reference.

Comment: Thanks @KeyurPATEL but its totally different.